# Ubuntu 20.04 Update fails from not found debian and linux_downloads Releases

Tags: package-management, 20.04, updates, virtualbox

When trying to use `sudo apt-get update` these errors occur. I have copy and pasted this from my terminal.

```
Hit:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kgilmer/speed-ricer/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Ign:9 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 'xenial' InRelease
Ign:10 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/sun_vbox.asc focal InRelease
Ign:11 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/Linux_Downloads focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian eoan InRelease
Err:13 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 'xenial' Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2.17.152.31 80]
Err:14 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/sun_vbox.asc focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2.17.152.31 443]
Err:15 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/Linux_Downloads focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2.17.152.31 80]
Reading package lists...
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian 'xenial' Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/Linux_Downloads focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/sun_vbox.asc focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Packages (contrib/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target Translations (contrib/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11 (contrib/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (contrib/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target DEP-11-icons (contrib/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
W: Target CNF (contrib/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:56 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/virtualbox.list:2
```

I have tried using the instructions and checking the keys from and following the instructions here at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads but I am not sure what to do next. I hope I have provided enough information. I could not find my problem posted else where.

Comment: I was very focused on the Err lines I never read that configured multiple times lines. I'll work on resolving those now. If you know a good start, that would help. Thank you for the warning!

Comment: I found some other questions with similar problems. :)